# How to add dynamic CSS source urls in Squishit?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, compression, squishit

How to add dynamic CSS source path/urls in Squishit?

```
 @Html.Raw(
        Bundle.Css()
        .Add("~/Styles/" + (ViewBag.SiteName ?? "default") + "/a.css")
        .Add("~/Styles/" + (ViewBag.SiteName ?? "default") + "/b.css")
        .Add("~/Styles/" + (ViewBag.SiteName ?? "default") + "/c.css")
        .Render("~/Styles/" + (ViewBag.SiteName ?? "default") + "/o#.css")
    )
```

This will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Dynamic type.

I converted the ViewBag.SiteName to String first before inserting it and it worked.